# Passing command line arguments to Python function in script

Tags: python

I have a function which requires command line arguments (with `optparse`), which looks something like this:

```
def foo():
    parser = optparse.OptionParser()
    parser.add_option("-i", dest="input")
    parser.add_option("-o", dest="output")
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()

    do_something(options.input, options.output)
    return
```

I need to call this function from another Python script.
Does anyone know how to pass arguments to this without making use of `os.system('foo -i input_path -o output_path')`?

Comment: Command line arguments are only for when you execute the script directly from the terminal, like `py main.py -i`. But if you want to run a function from within python you would `import` the other file and pass parameters to the function instead.

Comment: I know. That function was initially meant to be terminal called only, I just want to know if there is a quick way to terminal-like pass parameters without changing the structure.

Comment: Even if there is, I doubt its particularly readable and I would go with changing the structure if you need to do this. Couldn't you just call `do_something(input, output)` directly from the other module? As far as I can tell that would be the best solution in this case

Comment: Not really, there is way more than a single function: I need to call the whole main(), which does more than calling a single function.

Comment: Can you update your post to include your file directory and relevant files so I can take a look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible to change your structure to incorporate function arguments? If you are calling it from another script it would make it easier.

```
def foo(input, output):
    parser = optparse.OptionParser()
    parser.add_option("-i", dest="input")
    parser.add_option("-o", dest="output")
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
    if options.input:
        input=options.input
    if options.output:
        output=options.output
    do_something(input, output)
    return
```

Otherwise you can try subprocess when calling from the other script, as that allows you to use args

Comment: This could be a solution, obviously, but I'd like to keep it as clean as possible since I'm using others' module...